# postgresql inet ipv4 subnet group by largest subnet

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with records:

| id | subnet |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.230.44.0/24 |
| 2 | 10.230.0.0/16 |
| 3 | 192.168.2.0/30 |
| 4 | 192.168.2.0/24 |
| 5 | 172.168.6.4/30 |

I need to select only the largest subnet if subnets overlap then display only with a subnet with the largest prefix

Result:

| id | subnet |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 10.230.0.0/16 |
| 4 | 192.168.2.0/24 |
| 5 | 172.168.6.4/30 |

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And please only tag the relevant RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

Use `SPLIT_PART` as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
        row_number() over
         (partition by split_part(subnet,'.',1),  split_part(subnet,'.',2)                             
          order by split_part(subnet,'/',1),  to_number(split_part(subnet,'/',2),'999') desc) as rn
  From your_table t) t
Where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`inet` columns support ordering & the comparison operator `>>=` ([contained within or equals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html))

```
SELECT 
  id
, subnet 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id
  , subnet
  , NOT COALESCE(LAG(subnet) OVER (ORDER BY subnet) >>= subnet, false) is_largest_subnet
  FROM inets
  ) x
WHERE is_largest_subnet
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This query works for this example. But in my case the entries in the row are dynamic.
I use  
SELECT id, subnet,  subnet >> ANY(SELECT subnet FROM subnets) FROM subnets